# Node.js execa: how to finish writing to process' stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, pandoc, child-process

I'm trying to use execa to convert stdin to a docx file. The promise I await is hanging and never completes. I've tried terminating stdin with a `\n`, but that doesn't work.

```js
const process  = execa('pandoc', ['-', '-o', 'file.docx'])
process.stdin.write('input to be made into a docx file')
process.stdin.write('\n')
const result = await process
```

Comment: you might want to look at https://github.com/mb21/panwriter/blob/master/src/js/Exporter.js#L77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it. Node writable streams have a [`end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback) method.

```js
const process  = execa('pandoc', ['-', '-o', 'file.docx'])
process.stdin.write('input to be made into a docx file')
process.stdin.end();
const result = await process
```